# How to seal off exterior gap for the winter, temp fix till spring

Tags: walls, exterior

It’s just a small enclosed porch area that was added on long ago, previous owners let the bottom plate rot away then simply filled the gap with poured concrete that went up and covered the siding. I’ve since removed the extra concrete and rebuilt the walls from the inside. Not looking for a permanent fix, after the winter I’ll put new siding up and replace the exterior sheathing, but I do want to keep the outside elements outside. I thought I could drop a piece of wood outside and use some spray foam inside, or I could cut some plywood to fit between the joists on the inside and maybe just push dirt up along the outside edge.
Thanks for any tips to make this quick and easy!
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're really planning to fix it properly in the spring, and if you don't care if it looks pretty, just fill the hole with spray foam.